# Debian 7 vs Ubuntu Server 14.04 for 32-bit VM "network nodes"

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, ubuntu-server

I plan to make a number of small VM's (virtualbox) that will serve as networking nodes for various VPS servers, local *appliances*, private domain servers (AD), and various other web services provided only to certain registered/authenticated users.

I do not care about bleeding edge support on either, only security and the availability/support of any *power-tools* right out of the box.

Base network packages I plan to work with: DNSMasq, IPTables, some with Shorewall, 2 OpenVPN subnets, Maybe some SSH tunnels, and a few public NAT/hotspot access points. LVM devices (probably eventually RAID on some).

VM's will get 128MB RAM and 2GB storage each. 32-bit host and guest. No Xserver/sound on any. Planning to stick with stable packages, only applying security updates.

---

### Question

Which OS, Deb Wheezy or Ubu Trusty, given some of my constraints above:

- will work with fewer glitches, out of the box
- will have clear configuration instructions and defaults
- will run the lightest (cpu demand) (given standard tools and equal time spent configuration and tuning

Not trying to ask which is better, but which is least appropriate (how much do these two really differ when building from a minimal install). Shipped kernel and modules make a difference at this low of resources? Available default package versions? Does one just cooperate better **out of the box**?

With little more than 150 packages installed, are these two really much different, or did one team botch their *networking* debut for this release cycle.